# Android back to activity after validate

Tags: android

I'm making a registration form with 5 steps (5 activities, Similar to facebook signup form).
The 1st activity is to put email
The 2nd activity is to put name and so on.
 After the user complete all steps, i validate the field email (to avoid being duplicated) from the server side. What i want is, if the user email exist, i want to go back to 1st activity so the user can enter other email and the submit the form again to the server. Whats the best way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you use a ViewPager with 5 fragments and then just switch back to fragment 1 by calling pagerAdaper.setCurrentItem(0);

Answer (score 0):

In your LastActivity after some action.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,FirstActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent );
```

This flag clear recent Activity in the activities stack.

Comment: But how can i send data back to this activity so the user can submit the form with parameters previously filled?

Comment: `intent.putExtra("extraKey", extraParam);`
This filled intent with params, which you and this intent activity recieve by method `getIntent()`

Comment: Thanks again, I'm new here on this site. But when i try to vote, they say it requires 15 reputation.